# Parsing through a list in racket

Tags: racket

Given a list define:

```
(define list
 '((a1 20 (1 a2) (3 a3))
  (a2 10 (2 a4))
  (a3 10 (1 a5) (2 a6) (3 a7))
  (a4 21)
  (a5 12)
  (a6 6 (1 a4) (2 a5))

) )
```

How do you write a function (sub 'a1) would return a list (a2 a3).
I can find the list ((1 a2) (3 a3)) with the following code:

```
(define (sub val)
 (cdr(cdr(cond ((assq val list))
        (else 0)))))
```

But what do I do after that to get only the elements I want? I tried doing some recursion but that just lead in circles. Any advice would be appreciated.

Second question: a function to get a list of only "a" with a number value less than or equal to given input i.e (test 10) would return (a2 a3 a6)
I can check one a list but I'm stuck at how to go through all the list of list and append the values.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the `map` function. So, either use your own `sub` function like this:

```
(map cadr (sub 'a1))
```

Or change your function to include the `map`:

```
(define (sub val)
    (map cadr (cdr(cdr(cond ((assq val list))
        (else 0))))))
```

`(cadr lst)` is just a shortcut for `(car (cdr lst))`. My `Racket` skills are a bit rusty, so I will refrain from saying that your `sub` function is entirely correct or has any glitches.

Comment: Thank you. Another question if you can help. A function to get a list of only "a" with a number value less than or equal to given input i.e (test 10) would return (a2 a3 a6) I can check one list at a time  but I'm stuck at how to go through all the list of list and append the values.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Why would `a6` or `a3` fit in there, but `a7` not?